# Java and mysql - problems with ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, database

```
public int count(String table) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) from ?");
        prepStmt.setString(1, table);
        ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
        return rs.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR when counting " + table);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

When I pass count("students") I have got error:
"java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''students'' at line 1"

When I change my prepared statement to: ("select count(*) from students") I have got an error:
"java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set".

How to repair it?

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: "java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:492)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:1294)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:797)
 at DatabaseConnector.count(DatabaseConnector.java:137)
 at Main.main(Main.java:35)"

Comment: A table name cannot be a statement parameter. And you have to call `next()` on a result set before you call `get` methods on it.

Comment: So I have to make if statement to deal with table names?

Comment: Yes, JDBC parameters (`?`) can be placed at very specific locations only. You cannot use a JDBC parameter for a table name. And... don't forget to call `next()` before `getInt()`.